# change the date format in excel, date picker

Tags: excel, datepicker

Im using the date picker add in and the format of the date is with backslashes 01/02/2022. Preferable format is 01.02.2022. Is there a way to change this inside the add in rather then using `substitute` formula or `Format cells`.

I would use `substitute` formula but then SAP gui scripting seems like is not picking up another updated date, it just copies the date that was first entered as constant value.

Answer (score 0):

I just have changed the format on my pc (since excel picks the format from pc) and worked well but would be interesting if anyone can explain how it can be done without changing the format on pc.